# Adicionando linhas e colunas em tabela pelol DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estou com dificuldades na utilização do DOM para gerar uma tabela em HTML. Segue o meu código.

```
function table(){
let max=100;
let table = document.getElementById('tableNumber');

    table.innerHTML += '<tr>';


    for (let i=1; i<=max; i++){
        table.innerHTML += '<td> '+i+' </td>'; 
        if (i%10 == 0) {
            table.innerHTML += '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

Uma vez que ele não está fechando a linha quando o o resto de `i` por 10 for 0, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Vamos fazer do jeito mais apropriado? Escrever no DOM é gambiarra, vamos manipulá-lo como deve ser (de qualquer forma tinha erros de lógica no código original).

```js
function table() {
    let max = 100;
    let table = document.getElementById('tableNumber');
    let linha;
    for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 0) linha = table.insertRow();
        linha.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
    }
}
table();
```

```html
<table id = "tableNumber"></table>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/InsertRowAndCells.js).

Documentação: [`insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow), [`insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell), [`createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode).